# Proportionate or proportional?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm writing up some maths notes, and I'm unsure about the wording of a sentence. Which should I write?

> In the degree system of measure, angles are measured ***proportionate*** to 360 degrees ...

Or

> In the degree system of measure, angles are measured ***proportional*** to 360 degrees ...

My gut says, "proportionate."

Could someone explain which is more apt and why?

Comment: In the measurement of (in the first instance rotational rather than static) angles, the _degree_ is defined as 1/360 of a complete revolution.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm aware that 1 degree represents the measure of an angle that constitutes 1/360th of a complete revolution, is there something in the wording of my notes that contradicts that?

Comment: You asked what you should write.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a _Which is correct: 'The yoke of an egg is white', or 'The yoke of an egg are white'?_ question.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think either of them makes much sense.  You would be better off re-writing the sentence completely, to explain what you mean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks 'Which should I write' when the answer is 'Neither'.

Answer (score 4):

As for usage of [proportional vs proportionate:](http://grammarist.com/usage/proportional-proportionate/) :

> - **Something that is proportional** (1) forms a whole with other quantities, or (2) is considered quantitatively with respect to something else. **Proportionate** means in due proportion. The distinction is subtle, but proportionate describes something that is made that way by an active agent, and it often describes quantities that are difficult to measure. Proportional doesn’t necessarily involve an active agent, and it is the preferred term where actual measurements are concerned.
> - Still, because the difference between proportionate and proportional is so subtle, writers who don’t grasp it need not worry too much, because the words are indeed widely used interchangeably. When in doubt, use proportional, which is twice as common and broader in meaning.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angle%20proportional%20to%2Cangle%20proportionate%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cangle%20proportional%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cangle%20proportionate%20to%3B%2Cc0): angle proportional to vs angle proportionate to

Regarding your sentences, I'd suggest to say that angles are measured in degrees. One degree is  represented by 1/360 of a full rotation.

Comment: Why can't I go with proportional?

Comment: Proportional (according to your answer): "Is considered quantitatively with respect to something else" – an angle is measured with respect to a complete revolution, in the degree system of measure a complete revolution is 360 degrees, so can I not say that angles in the degree system of measure are measured ***proportional*** to 360 degrees?

Comment: From your sentences I understand you are referring to the specific way and angle in measured..that is in degrees. Proportional/proportionate (as explained above) are used in different contexts, mainly to indicate a comparison/ relation between two entities. See examples here: http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/proportional

Comment: Please check also the sentences you can find in Ngram I included above with ' angle proportional to'.

Answer (score 1):

### The truth

It don't matter none.

### You put a gun to my head and make me choose

Proportional.

### Why?

The root word in ancient Latin is the same for both words. Some medieval boneheads invented a Latin word for no obvious reasons and it entered English as "proportionate." Many dictionaries have circular definitions: proportional means proportionate; proportionate means proportional. They are the same word.

Nevertheless, some people believe there must or should be a distinction, so if you would like to find a distinction between the two words, then what @Josh61 quoted is the basic idea.

Use proportional if you have an Object X that is a portion of Object Y and you can add more X to your original amount and eventually have a whole Y. In your case, if you have an angle of 10 degrees in a unit circle, then you can add more degrees to your original 10 degrees to get an entire circle. (The previous statement is accurate, but not precise.)

Use proportionate if two different objects are appropriately analogous or comparable. In law, for example, one example of proportionate is the cliche, ["the punishment should fit the crime."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28law%29)

Two excellent sources that I cribbed from:

- The Grammarphobia Blog, [*The right proportions*](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/08/the-right-proportions.html)
- *[Proportionate vs. Proportional](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/proportionate-vs-proportional/)* By Maeve Maddox

### Addendum

@seeker, much of the hostility towards your question has nothing to do with your question. Rather, some people are reacting to the fact that your writing style is not elegant. Inelegant writing is not a crime, and this is not a forum for discussing pretty prose. Your question is exactly what this forum is for: how to use modern English so that you comport with the consensus of grammar and spelling.

To illustrate, one comment to another answer reads:

> @seeker Have you ever heard of the 'mile' system of measure or the
>   'metre' system of measure? I very much doubt it. We usually say
>   'measuring in miles' or 'using metres'. And we'd never say 'Distances
>   are measured proportional to miles'. –  Edwin Ashworth

The commentator is correct that most writers would use "measuring in miles" and not "the mile system of measure." Nevertheless, both forms have the same meaning: the difference is not grammar--the difference is style. Your particular style has distracted some readers from seeing the content of your question, and caused a few commentators to argue that your use of the word "proportion" is patently wrong. To show that you are using the word properly, I will recast your sentence using a more conventional style.

> When measuring angles, the [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (SI) uses a unit of measurement called a "[radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)." For thousands of years, many people used a unit of measurement called a "degree," and SI recognizes the entrenchment of measuring angles in degrees, so they label it an "[accepted unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle))" of measure but it is not an official SI unit of measurement.
>
> The size of one degree is derived from splitting a circle into 360 identical slices. Therefore, one degree (1°) is a 1/360 portion of a circle. All angles measured in degrees are in proportion to assuming that a circle is 360°. For example, if an angle is 90°, then its proportion is one-fourth of the degrees in a circle, and it happens to look like a "right angle."

"Proportion," or some derivative of it, is an acceptable word to describe your ideas. Whether or not they are more elegant ways to describe these mathematical concepts is irrelevant here.

Good luck with your notes!

Comment: It only 'doesn't matter none' if anyone can use English any way they choose. Which would make this site pointless. As Jonno says and others had already intimated, 'Both _proportionate_ and _proportional_ are inappropriate'.

Comment: Addendum to clarify that proportion is an acceptable word.

Comment: But that's not what OP asked. He asked **one of his two sentences** (both using 'some derivative of proportion') was acceptable. And neither is. In maths, one variable is proportional to another; it doesn't make sense to say 'x is proportional to the constant, 360 degrees'. I can't accept your 'a few commentators ... argue that your use of the word "proportion" is patently wrong. To show that you are using the word properly, I will recast your sentence using a more conventional style.' as being tenable on this site. The words under discussion here are _proportionate_ and _proportional_....

Comment: Try telling a new boss who is preparing a new scheme of work that they are 'scheming'. 'What is 3 of 4?' doesn't work for 'What is 3 times 4?', whereas 'What is .5 of 4?' does work for 'What is .5 times 4?'. The exact way words are used is as important as whether or not they have a connected meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Both proportionate and proportional are inappropriate. You are talking about a circle, which may be divided into segments, each one of which is a 360th part of the whole circle. As far as I know there is no "degree system of measure". Degrees are not part of a measurement system. Every circle in a plane contains 360 degrees, no matter how big the circle is. That is why Pi is a constant. Try  "Every circle contains 360 degrees..."

Comment: There is, there's also the "radian" system of measure, and various other systems of measure. Degrees aren't the only way of measuring an angle.

Comment: @seeker Have you ever heard of the 'mile' system of measure or the 'metre' system of measure? I very much doubt it. We usually say 'measuring in miles' or 'using metres'. And we'd never say 'Distances are measured proportional to miles'.