Are 'proportional' and 'proportionate' slightly different in usage?
Recently the headlines have been about the kind of response that Governments wish to take in regard to world events.
The headlines seem evenly divided as to 'proportional' response or 'proportionate' response.
As far as I can see, it is not a matter of AmE and BrE.
Am I correct in thinking that some are using 'proportional' to refer to a specific, proposed activity and 'proportionate' to describe an underlying  policy ?

Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225144/proportionate-or-proportional

My dictionary says they're synonyms. But "proportionate" is also often used to mean "appropriate", e.g. "The return fire was proportionate, considering the attack."

The linked answer seems good, but I don't think the distinction is subtle. Suppose your enemy fires 3 rockets at you. A proportional response is to fire 3, 6, 9 or 12 rockets back. A proportionate response is to first 3 or 4 rockets back.

I don’t think there’s a distinction between activities and policies. As use note, both are currently in use in response to acts requiring retaliation.


The word proportionate typically reflects a qualitative judgement that a magnitude, extent or importance, appraised approximately, is appropriate relative to another, or that two measures are in balance. It connotes fairness, and is synonymous with commensurate.

The word proportional technically refers to two quantities varying in a fixed ratio; for example, retaliation is proportional to provocation if the former is always triple the latter.
Now, if the enemy provocatively fires 3 missiles, is firing 10 missiles considered a "proportional" response? Sure, if you'd be correspondingly firing 40 missiles had they fired 12.


While these two words are often used interchangeably, 'proportionate' is the straightforward, more natural word choice to describe consequences and responses (e.g., crime being proportionate to punishment)—and generally the more direct and accessible option for headlines and non-technical contexts.

+1. The origin of the confusion is perhaps the noun "proportionality" that refers to both senses, i.e. a mathematical ratio or the idea that an action should not be more severe than is necessary.

"Proportionality" in mathematics refers to the constancy of the ratio of two quantities X and Y (Sense 2), rather than the equality of the two quantities' degree/magnitude (Sense 1).

Source and/or example usages?

@TinfoilHat I've just added a 'crime vs punishment' example on top of the 'missiles' one, but didn't look for sources because I reckon that this Answer is uncontroversial.
